# Newbie, XSLT Transformation from XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new in learning XPath and XSLT, so I need some help with one task.

I need to transform this XML using XSLT:

```
<top>
    <name>
        <last>Crockett</last>
        <first type="formal">David</first>
        <first type="informal">Davy</first>
    </name>
    <name>
        <last>Baseball</last>
        <first type="formal">Bryan</first>
        <first type="informal">Hollow</first>
    </name>
    <name>
        <last>Crockett</last>
        <first type="formal">Josephine</first>
        <first type="informal">Wendel</first>
    </name>
    <name>
        <last>Baseball</last>
        <first type="formal">Michael</first>
        <first type="informal">Wolf</first>
    </name>
    <name>
        <last>Crockett</last>
        <first type="formal">Bisera</first>
        <first type="informal">Ivanovic</first>
    </name>
</top>
```

To this XML:

```
<Zookeepers>
    <Crockett>
        <candidate>
            <first>David</first>
            <last>Davy</last>
        </candidate>
        <candidate>
            <first>Josephine</first>
            <last>Wendel</last>
        </candidate>
        <candidate>
            <first>Bisera</first>
            <last>Ivanovic</last>
        </candidate>
    </Crockett>
    <Baseball>
        <candidate>
            <first>Bryan</first>
            <last>Hollow</last>
        </candidate>
        <candidate>
            <first>Michael</first>
            <last>Wolf</last>
        </candidate>
    </Baseball>
</Zookeepers>
```

The output of the XML file should look like that.

This is what I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="Zookeepers">
     <xsl:element name="Candidate">
<xsl:element name="Crockett">



      <xsl:apply-templates select="top/name/last"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top/name/last">
   <xsl:element name="first" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>

   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A person who works with integration development gave me this task, as you can see my level is low, I'm a newbie but I'm willing to learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.  --- See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66795559/3016153

Comment: I can't work my way with your example, i get stuck, it's  really frustrating....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group `name` elements by `last`.

Since you're using XSLT 1.0 you'd need to use [the Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

This means creating a key (matching `name` and using `last`).

Then you need to iterate over each of the first `name` elements that contain the matching key (this is the part of Muenchian grouping that you can either use `generate-id()` or `count()`).

By using the value of `last` you can create the `Crockett` and `Baseball` elements.

Then iterate over all of the `name` elements in the matching key. These all become the `candidate` elements.

All that's left is to process the `first` elements (don't process `last`), strip the `type` attribute of the `first` elements, and change the `first` elements to `last` when the `type` attribute equals "informal".

Give it a shot yourself, but here's an example just in case you get stuck...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="name_by_last" match="name" use="last"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Zookeepers>
            <xsl:for-each select="name[count(.|key('name_by_last',last)[1])=1]">
                <xsl:element name="{last}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('name_by_last',last)">
                        <candidate>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="first"/>
                        </candidate>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Zookeepers>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="first[@type='informal']">
        <last>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </last>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="first/@*"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very informative link.